# Command line using an array with spaces

Tags: arrays, bash, positional-parameter

How can I pass an array where some values have spaces.
I mean:

script.sh

```
#/bin/bash
echo $1, $#
```

I can run this little script

```
$ ./script.sh a --> a, 1
$ ./script.sh "a b" --> a b, 1
$ v=("a b" c)
$ ./script.sh ${v[@]} --> a, 3
$ ./script.sh ${v[@]@Q} --> 'a, 3
```

I would like to print "a b, 2" without changing the script
Is it possible?

The only way I have found to achive it is:

```
eval "./script.sh ${v[@]@Q}" --> a b, 2
```

Is there a smarter way?

Comment: Like that `./script.sh "${v[0]}"`?

Comment: Thanks. In this case I would be right but I want to use all the values in the array. I'm going to rewrite the example

Comment: `"${array[@]}"` expands to all values in an array. So, `./script "${v[@]}"` -- no `eval` needed.

Comment: Note that **the quotes are not optional**; `${array[@]}` does something subtly different (identical to unquoted `${array[*]}`, which is to say, combining all array elements with the first character in IFS, then word-splitting the result and glob-expanding each resulting word).

Comment: ...I closed with a duplicate that speaks about "functions" in its title, but the answer is fully applicable to external/regular commands as well.

Comment: Charles, that's it. I have spend several hours trying everything but "${array[@]}". Thanks